# What is the probability of winning at most two star stickers in rounds 3, 4, 5, 6 given that four star stickers are won in $10$ rounds?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I've created this "tree" for the question:
[image]
A single game round is defined as follows: player throws a stone 2 times on a board with numbers from 1-8 (assume that a stone always falls inside the board) If the sum of the results of the parts on which the stone fell, in both throws is:

At most 5: The player proceed to the area T $[I1]$.

At least 12: Go to W $[I2]$.

Else: Go to G $[I3]$.

What's going inside T,G,W doesn't matter (I calculated all already, look in the picture).

$A,B,C$ meaning player won a ***"star sticker"***, $notA,notB,notC$ meaning player won a ***"cup"***.
$P(winning-star sticker) = 0.485$

The question I don't understand how to solve is:  Knowing that the player played $10$ rounds and won $4$ ***"star stickers"***, calculate the probability that he got at most $2$ "star stickers" from the rounds 3,4,5,6.

*If anyone is interested, I can post full question.

Comment: In order to answer your question, we need to know how to calculate the probability that a player wins a star sticker in a given round.

Comment: i edited,added the probability that a player wins a star sticker in a given round: P(winning−starsticker)=0.485

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, the probability of winning exactly four star stickers in $10$ rounds is $\Pr(X = 4) = \binom{10}{4}(0.485)^4(1 - 0.485)^6$, where I have used the binomial distribution since the probability of winning a star sticker is the same for each round.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes the probability of winning exactly four start stickers in 10 rounds ive got the same, but the question is: we know that he won 4stars in 10 rounds what is the probability that at most 2 of those star stickers won in rounds 3 to 6 (3,4,5,6) (hope i made it clearer ^^)

Comment: You should include your own work on the question in your post.  For instance, you could include the definition of conditional probability and the work you did to calculate the probability that exactly four star stickers were obtained in four rounds.  You could also specify that you were having trouble calculating the numerator.

Comment: Thank you very much!, will do next time

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be the event that at most two star stickers are won in the rounds $3, 4, 5, 6$.  Let $F$ be the event that exactly four star stickers are won in the ten rounds.  We wish to find
$$\Pr(E \mid F) = \frac{\Pr(E \cap F)}{\Pr(F)}$$

Since the probability of winning in each round is $0.485$, the probability of winning exactly four times in ten rounds is
$$\Pr(F) = \binom{10}{4}(0.485)^{4}(1 - 0.485)^6$$
where we have used the binomial distribution with $n = 10$ trials, $p = 0.485$, and $k = 4$ successes.

For the favorable cases, notice that if exactly $j$ star stickers are won in rounds $3, 4, 5, 6$, then exactly $4 - j$ star stickers must be won in the remaining six rounds.  The probability of winning exactly $j$ star stickers in rounds $3, 4, 5, 6$ is
$$\binom{4}{j}(0.485)^j(1 - 0.485)^{4 - j}$$
The probability of winning exactly $4 - j$ star stickers in rounds $1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10$ is
$$\binom{6}{4 - j}(0.485)^{4 - j}(1 - 0.485)^{6 - (4 - j)}$$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(E \cap F) & = \sum_{j = 0}^{2} \binom{4}{j}(0.485)^j(1 - 0.485)^{4 - j}\binom{6}{4 - j}(0.485)^{4 - j}(1 - 0.485)^{6 - (4 - j)}\\
       & = \sum_{j = 0}^{2} \binom{4}{j}\binom{6}{4 - j}(0.485)^4(1 - 0.485)^{6}
\end{align*}

Comment: Note that I corrected an error that was in the final line of my original answer.  The $\binom{6}{j}$ in the original answer should have been $\binom{6}{4 - j}$ since there are a total of $j + 4 - j = 4$ successes in $10$ rounds.